# how do I display a chapter in the man?

Tags: unix

use the man command to find a command to determine a file type. The man command with
  the -k keyword option will display all commands. I want you to display only commands in chapter 1 of the Unix man pages

Answer (score 1):

It's usually called 'sections' not chapters.

It also may depend on your UNIX version. Do you mean Linux?

I couldn't find a flag that would limit it, but you can do it with grep

```
man -k open | fgrep '(1)'
```

Would show 'open' but limit to section 1.